# SQL JOIN fail - not a unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, sql, smf-forum

```
SELECT `member_name.smf_members`, COUNT(`author.smf_links`) 
FROM smf_members, smf_links
JOIN smf_links ON id_member.smf_members = author.smf_links;
GROUP BY `author.smf_links`
```

It says smf_links is not a unique table/alias. All I want to do is make it get a count of how many rows has the same author, and show the member name instead of the author (which is a number) and the count.

So instead of:
1 | 23

It would show:
Bunny | 23

I can't figure this out and my brain has gone numb from googling. Can someone please help me out? :)

Comment: `member_name.smf_members` parameter will show probably Bunny, isn't it? Maybe member_id or something will solve your problem

Comment: Do you really need to join with `smf_links` twice? You have both an implicit join and an explicit join with the same table.

Comment: I only want to show the name though, not the id. The id is what I want to join on.

Barmar what do you mean?

Comment: You have `FROM smf_members, smf_links JOIN smf_links`. The first one is an implicit join, the second one is an explicit join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you're joining with the same table, `smf_links`, twice. If that's what you really want to do, you need to give them aliases so you can distinguish them. But I suspect you did that by mistake.

Also, the syntax is `tablename.column`, not `column.table`. And you have to put the backticks around each part separately; if the `.` is inside the backticks, it's treated as a literal character, not a delimiter.

```
SELECT `smf_members`.`member_name`, COUNT(*)
FROM smf_members
JOIN smf_links ON smf_members.id_member = smf_links.author
GROUP BY smf_links.author
```

Comment: That got it, thank you!

Not entirely sure how it knew to count the links table rows. Would you mind explaining that? :)

Comment: `JOIN` creates a cross-product, and `COUNT(*)` counts the rows in that cross-product. You don't need to put a column name in `COUNT()` unless you need to not count rows where that column is `NULL`.

Comment: Oh, right, thank you so much! I am a little rusty I admit. Still thinking of things too rigidly/literally.